# What does COMMAND in 'docker ps' mean?

Tags: docker

`docker ps` or `docker container ls` returns an overview of all running containers. The meaning of all columns is clear to me, except one. What does the column 'COMMAND' mean?

[image]

Comment: We would much rather have the text rather than images

Comment: It's the command that was executed when the container was started. It's going to be `ENTRYPOINT` + `CMD` from Dockerfile. If you want to see the whole command you can use `--no-trunc` flag (`docker ps --help` or `docker container ls --help`), e.g `docker ps -a --no-trunc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the command which is passed to the container.

```
$ docker run -d busybox top
$docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID     IMAGE      COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS        PORTS    NAMES
3eca7c034b21     busybox    "top"       6 seconds ago  Up 5 seconds           recursing_dirac
```

If you check above, ***top*** is the command which has been passed to the busybox container and that's what it's showing in the `docker ps -a`.

Comment: Not entirely correct. It is sometimes the command, sometimes the entrypoint, sometimes both.

Answer (score 2):

It's the command passed to `docker run <image> [command]`.

```
$ docker run -d ubuntu sleep 60
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID      IMAGE      COMMAND        CREATED           STATUS
f0c9cd92a938      ubuntu     "sleep 60"     3 seconds ago     Up 1 second
```

If no command was specified there then it's the `CMD` from the Dockerfile. In [`ubuntu`'s case](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/857debd4347496c541f9806c084710dace49cd27/bionic/Dockerfile) that would be `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`:

```
$ docker run -di ubuntu
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID      IMAGE      COMMAND        CREATED           STATUS
9cd752ee86f4      ubuntu     "/bin/bash"    4 seconds ago     Up 2 seconds
```

Comment: Actually, it's a mix of entrypoint and cmd depending on how those things are mixed in the dockerfile(s) and command-line.